# Is it good style in fiction to write sentences as a flow of (disjointed) thoughts?

Tags: style, fiction

I was wondering whether it is okay to write like this or not:

> I never went for the grooves. But I did take a seat near the bar table and checked out the pretty ladies. Drinking was not my cup of tea. Alcohol. Alcohol was not my cup of tea. Wait, let me reframe it. . . I did not drink.

Can I write sentences like these - 'okay wait, let me reframe it. . .  I did not drink.'

Share some light?

Comment: Proofreading requests are off-topic here, I'm closing this.

Comment: I wish I could downvote moderator decisions. This is not a request for proofreading a specific sentence, this is a question about using certain tools of style.

Comment: @Neil, actually, this was not proofreading.

Comment: I can see if this is closed for being subjective (which it is) but it's not about proofreading.

Comment: @XORGate - I assumed it was a proofreading question because you used the proofreading tag. There's also no real question here; you're just asking people to tell you what they think of the sentence.

Comment: @Neil, I never asked how this sentence was. I just asked whether it is a good practice to write in this style or not. 
But it's my bad. I should not have used that tag.

Comment: Proofreading tag aside, there are a couple of ways you could take this. If you want a critique of your text, you'll need to provide more than a sentence or three and also provide specific questions. Our [critique guidelines](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/a/489/26) may be of help. **Or** - Perhaps what you want to refocus this so it's asking about writing in a conversational manner? If so, I'd suggest expanding the question to focus on that.

Comment: @JohnSmithers I like your title change.

Comment: @JohnSmithers, thanks for the title change. 
I really need to learn how to frame my questions. :|

Comment: Perhaps, instead of asking if this is "good style", you could ask what effect this kind of writing will have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Is it okay..." and "Can I..." are subjective. It's about context.

Are the sentences grammatically correct? Strictly speaking, no. But you are clearly writing in a first-person, casual, stream-of-consciousness dictation style, so they are perfectly fine for that.

Speaking as an editor, as long as this is your character's/narrator's voice, and you're consistent, I would be entirely fine with this type of writing, and wouldn't mark it up to be "fixed."

Comment: Thanks Lauren. This is what most of the youth in my country like. Hence the writing style. :)